# Writing juridical documents with Latex

Tags: document-classes

I would like to start building some juridical documents with LaTeX but the ecosystem is too big and I don't know where to start from!
If someone could enlighten me, I would like to build documents like these:
[image]

Circled in red, the address to where the document will be sent. I need this only on the first page.

Circled in blue, the title of the document
Circled in purple, the sections of the document (there will be at least 3 of them)

The layout is simple and for what I've saw until now, people use LaTeX for very complex documents and, trying to start something using the report documentclass or the article documentclass didn't feel right.
Can anyone help me where to begin with?

Comment: The `article` class is useful for many different types of document, not just research articles. Many other classes are built with `article` as the base class. You can definitely make a layout like your example with `article`. Look into the `geometry` package for changing the page margins. If you want to generate documents automatically from an external data source then there are some packages that do that, but often it is easier to generate the code for the documents in another programming language and process the resulting documents with LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elaborating on Leonardo's answer, here is another take on this. You may change the fonts, margins, or whatever.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %showframe
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%%caracteres latinos
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\normalsize}


\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\section*{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS
EXCELENTÍSSIMO SENHOR DOUTOR JUIZ DE DIREITO DA 000ª VARA CÍVEL DA COMARCA DE XXXXXX}


(Nome), (nacionalidade), (estado civil), (profissão), portador da carteira de identidade RG n° xxxxxxx e inscrito no CPF/MF sob n° xxxxxxx, residente e domiciliado na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), por seu advogado que esta subscreve, constituído na forma do incluso instrumento de mandato, vem, a presença de Vossa Excelência, propor a presente.

\section*{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS}

contra (Razão social), pessoa jurídica de direito privado, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob n° xxxxxx, sediada na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), consubstanciado nos motivos fáticos e de direito a seguir aduzidos:

\subsection*{DOS FATOS}

O autor foi até o Banco Tal para obter empréstimo no valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor), para comprar as ferramentas necessárias para uma pequena oficina de máquinas de costura.

Depois das exigências do Banco, onde o autor já havia superado todas, foi surpreendido com a negativação da concessão do numerário almejado.

Ao indagar, junto à gerência, o motivo de o Banco não liberar o empréstimo, mais uma vez foi surpreendido com a informação de que em seu nome havia restrição junto ao Serviço de Proteção ao Crédito.

Pediu ao funcionário do Banco que lhe desse tal informação por escrito, pois tinha certeza de que não devia nada a ninguém, senão seria desprovido de vergonha em querer um empréstimo, sabendo das normas do Banco, e em seguida passar por uma vergonha sem valores para o respeito, que até então havia conquistado junto àquela instituição.

O documento, que o autor recebeu do Banco, traz a informação de que seu nome consta no rol dos inadimplentes por atraso no pagamento de conta telefônica, datada de xx/xx/xx e com valor facial de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor).

Ocorre que o autor nunca ficou devendo nenhuma conta para a ré, e que ao buscar explicações junto à empresa ré foi informado que houve um erro de comunicação junto ao órgão de proteção ao crédito, porém que caberia a ele providenciar a retirada do seu nome do rol dos inadimplentes.

Indignado, o autor exigiu que retirassem seu nome daquela lista, obtendo a resposta de que fariam, mas isto levaria tempo.

Assim o autor teve seu nome negativado, sem dever nada a ninguém, por um período de trinta e cinco dias, e neste período teve prejuízos incalculáveis para a sua realidade econômica.

Toda esta narrativa de fatos objetiva dar a perfeita interação sobre o ocorrido, que pode ser sintetizado nos seguintes termos: ficou claro que a ré, de forma irresponsável, deixou que se incluísse o nome do autor no rol dos inadimplentes do serviço de proteção ao crédito, trazendo ao autor grande prejuízo, pois buscava empréstimo para iniciar um pequeno negócio de concerto de máquinas de costura, e ao questionar o ocorrido a autora não obteve nenhuma resposta plausível que solucionasse o caso imediatamente, sofrendo grande prejuízo.

Assim, nada mais justo, venha o autor requerer judicialmente uma reparação por tal fato.

\subsection*{DO DIREITO}

Em nosso direito é certa e pacífica a tese de que quando alguém viola um interesse de outrem, juridicamente protegido, fica obrigado a reparar o dano daí decorrente. Basta adentrar na esfera jurídica alheia, para que venha certa a responsabilidade civil.

E no caso particular, deve-se considerar que dano é "qualquer lesão injusta a componentes do complexo de valores protegidos pelo Direito".

No mesmo entendimento de dano material, temos a definição clara e objetiva de que a subtração de um objeto de outrem deverá devolver a coisa em espécie, e se o objeto não mais existir, deverá o esbulhador pagar o preço ordinário da coisa, ou repor o numerário a título de dano material, além do valor referente ao dano moral do autor, que ao buscar um empréstimo, junto ao banco, teve resposta negativa por motivos alheio a sua vontade.

Sendo assim, não há como confundir a reparabilidade do dano material e do dano moral. Na primeira busca-se a reposição do numerário que deu causa ao prejuízo sofrido, ao passo que na segunda, a reparação se faz por meio de uma compensação ou reparação que satisfaça o autor pelo mal sofrido.

Pois bem, adentrando na análise legal do tema, inicialmente é oportuno fazer referência à Constituição Federal de 1988, que foi muito clara ao dispor, no seu art. 5º, inciso X, "in verbis":

" X - são invioláveis a intimidade, a vida privada, a honra e a imagem das pessoas, assegurado o direito a indenização pelo dano material ou moral decorrente de sua violação".

Sem, também deixarmos claro que o legislador não deixou de pronunciar esta garantia de direito ao consumidor, que no caso em tela tem claramente uma relação de consumo entre autor e ré, onde pedimos vênia para transcrever:

Código de Defesa do Consumidor


    ``V a efetiva prevenção e reparação de danos patrimoniais e morais, individuais, coletivos e difusos";

Além de incansáveis decisões assegurando o direito líquido e certo de quem se encontrar lesado por fato

<< Pesquisar Jurisprudência >>

E, por estarem tais argumentos, cabe lembrar que estão presentes os pressupostos da responsabilidade civil deste resultado danoso.

Pois bem, superada toda essa discussão, nesse momento é imprescindível a discussão a respeito de outro assunto de extrema relevância nesta demanda: o "quantum" a ser fixado.

Logo de início, é importante considerar que a reparação, na qual se convertem em pecúnia os danos morais, devem ter caráter dúplice, ou seja, o que penaliza o ofensor, sancionando-o para que não volte a praticar o ato ilícito, bem como o compensatório, para que o ofendido, recebendo determinada soma pecuniária, possa amenizar os efeitos decorrentes do ato que foi vítima.

Ante esse raciocínio, deve-se sopesar, em cada caso concreto, todas as circunstâncias que possam influenciar na fixação do "quantum" indenizatório, levando em consideração que o dano moral abrange, além das perdas valorativas internas, as exteriorizadas no relacionamento diário pessoal, familiar, profissional e social do ofendido.

Deve-se lembrar ainda, por outro ângulo, que a indenização por danos morais deve ser fixada num montante que sirva de aviso à ré e à sociedade, como um todo, de que o nosso direito não tolera aquela conduta danosa impunemente, devendo a condenação atingir efetivamente, de modo muito significativo, o patrimônio da causadora do dano, para que assim o Estado possa demonstrar que o Direito existe para ser cumprido.

\subsection*{DO PEDIDO}

Posto isso, requer a Vossa Excelência:

A citação da ré, no endereço inicialmente referido, para comparecer na audiência de instrução e julgamento a ser designada, e, querendo, apresentar resposta, sob pena de revelia e confissão quanto à matéria de fato;

Se digne Vossa Excelência considerar procedente o seu pedido, para o fim de condenar a ré ao pagamento de indenização no valor de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor), pelos danos materiais, mais o valor a ser arbitrado por Vossa Excelência em salários mínimos referentes ao dano moral, bem como das custas processuais e honorários advocatícios, na base de xx% sobre o valor da condenação, tudo com a devida atualização.

Os benefícios da justiça gratuita, previsto na Lei 1.060/50, por ser o autor pessoa pobre na acepção jurídica do termo, não podendo arcar com as despesas processuais sem que cause prejuízos para sua sobrevivência.

\subsection*{DAS PROVAS}

Protesta por todos os meios de prova em direito admitidos, depoimentos de testemunhas, bem como novas provas, documentais e outras, que eventualmente venham a surgir.

\subsection*{DO VALOR DA CAUSA}

Dá-se à causa o valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor).

Termos em que

Pede Deferimento.

(Local, data, ano).

\vfill

\begin{center}
\rule{6cm}{.4pt}\\
    Advogado: Fulano\\
    OAB-PR 123 \\
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

**Edit**

If you need *all* centered sections, just change

`\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\normalsize}`

to

`\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\normalsize\centering}`.

Comment: No `br-lex`? I am disappointed. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, I guess `br-lex` is just for transcribing whole pieces of law. `;-)`

Comment: iI think that to quote an article from the law the enumitem package is enough ;)
              

\begin{enumerate}[label = \bfseries Art. \arabic*.]
\setcounter{enumi}{<article number>-1}
....
\end{enumerate}

Comment: @leonardocesar, to quote just _one_ article, or even _many_, it's too much effort for such paltry one-time results. But the end-user can judge for himself.

Comment: I really liked the output that I got from your template. How can I center the section titles?
BTW: Thank you for the answer! I would like to learn how to fish and instead got the entire fish :) And, of course, I learned a lot!

Comment: @CarlsonWeberFilho, Glad you deemed it useful. Do you want to center them all?

Comment: @Joseph, sure! All the sections need to be centered and the body full justified.

Comment: @CarlsonWeberFilho, then just add `\centering` to `\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\normalsize}`, thus: `\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\normalsize\centering}`. I've modified the answer accordingly, feel free to accept it as answered if it thus satisfies thy needs.

Answer (score 4):

I interpreted you question as you needed the coloured boxes around the address, title and section. I have used `scrartcl` from the [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle as basis, because it is pretty easy to modify (save for adding the box around the section title). That code is copied from the manual and modified. I also copied the text from @Joseph's answer.

In your example, the whole document is typeset in  *sans serif* so I use Helvetica.

The option `parskip=true` ensure that you have paragraph without first line indentation, and as an build in option, it also secure compatibility with other commands and fair spacing in rest of the document. I have defined two commands that set the address and title. It is possible to redefine internal commands instead. Do you prefer narrower margins? Just increase the number after DIV, for example to `DIV=10`.

The package [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) secure better line breaks with less hyphenation. And [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) ensure that you have correct citation marks for Brazil.

The title has limitation: If you need titles with more than one line, the command has to be modified.

If you have questions, just ask.

[image]

```
\documentclass[brazil, fontsize=10pt, headings=small, DIV=9, parskip=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=-2pt plus -2pt minus -1pt,%
afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp%
]{section}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\@tempswafalse
\ifstr{#1}{section}{%
\hspace*{#2}%
\fcolorbox{purple}{white}{%
\raggedsection
\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}%
}{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
}%
}\makeatother

%% Setting up the document


\let\raggedsection\centering   % Centred sections


\newcommand{\address}[1]{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedright\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\doctitle}[1]{\begin{center}\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}\end{center}}


\begin{document}

\address{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS
EXCELENTÍSSIMO SENHOR DOUTOR JUIZ DE DIREITO DA 000ª VARA CÍVEL DA COMARCA DE XXXXXX}


(Nome), (nacionalidade), (estado civil), (profissão), portador da carteira de identidade RG n xxxxxxx e inscrito no CPF/MF sob n xxxxxxx, residente e domiciliado na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), por seu advogado que esta subscreve, constituído na forma do incluso instrumento de mandato, vem, a presença de Vossa Excelência, propor a presente.

\doctitle{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS}

contra (Razão social), pessoa jurídica de direito privado, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob n xxxxxx, sediada na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), consubstanciado nos motivos fáticos e de direito a seguir aduzidos:

\section*{DOS FATOS}

O autor foi até o Banco Tal para obter empréstimo no valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor), para comprar as ferramentas necessárias para uma pequena oficina de máquinas de costura.

Depois das exigências do Banco, onde o autor já havia superado todas, foi surpreendido com a negativação da concessão do numerário almejado.

Ao indagar, junto à gerência, o motivo de o Banco não liberar o empréstimo, mais uma vez foi surpreendido com a informação de que em seu nome havia restrição junto ao Serviço de Proteção ao Crédito.

Pediu ao funcionário do Banco que lhe desse tal informação por escrito, pois tinha certeza de que não devia nada a ninguém, senão seria desprovido de vergonha em querer um empréstimo, sabendo das normas do Banco, e em seguida passar por uma vergonha sem valores para o respeito, que até então havia conquistado junto àquela instituição.

O documento, que o autor recebeu do Banco, traz a informação de que seu nome consta no rol dos inadimplentes por atraso no pagamento de conta telefônica, datada de xx/xx/xx e com valor facial de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor).


Ocorre que o autor nunca ficou devendo nenhuma conta para a ré, e que ao buscar explicações junto à empresa ré foi informado que houve um erro de comunicação junto ao órgão de proteção ao crédito, porém que caberia a ele providenciar a retirada do seu nome do rol dos inadimplentes.

Indignado, o autor exigiu que retirassem seu nome daquela lista, obtendo a resposta de que fariam, mas isto levaria tempo.

Assim o autor teve seu nome negativado, sem dever nada a ninguém, por um período de trinta e cinco dias, e neste período teve prejuízos incalculáveis para a sua realidade econômica.

Toda esta narrativa de fatos objetiva dar a perfeita interação sobre o ocorrido, que pode ser sintetizado nos seguintes termos: ficou claro que a ré, de forma irresponsável, deixou que se incluísse o nome do autor no rol dos inadimplentes do serviço de proteção ao crédito, trazendo ao autor grande prejuízo, pois buscava empréstimo para iniciar um pequeno negócio de concerto de máquinas de costura, e ao questionar o ocorrido a autora não obteve nenhuma resposta plausível que solucionasse o caso imediatamente, sofrendo grande prejuízo.

Assim, nada mais justo, venha o autor requerer judicialmente uma reparação por tal fato.

\section*{DO DIREITO}

Em nosso direito é certa e pacífica a tese de que quando alguém viola um interesse de outrem, juridicamente protegido, fica obrigado a reparar o dano daí decorrente. Basta adentrar na esfera jurídica alheia, para que venha certa a responsabilidade civil.

E no caso particular, deve-se considerar que dano é "qualquer lesão injusta a componentes do complexo de valores protegidos pelo Direito".

No mesmo entendimento de dano material, temos a definição clara e objetiva de que a subtração de um objeto de outrem deverá devolver a coisa em espécie, e se o objeto não mais existir, deverá o esbulhador pagar o preço ordinário da coisa, ou repor o numerário a título de dano material, além do valor referente ao dano moral do autor, que ao buscar um empréstimo, junto ao banco, teve resposta negativa por motivos alheio a sua vontade.

Sendo assim, não há como confundir a reparabilidade do dano material e do dano moral. Na primeira busca-se a reposição do numerário que deu causa ao prejuízo sofrido, ao passo que na segunda, a reparação se faz por meio de uma compensação ou reparação que satisfaça o autor pelo mal sofrido.

Pois bem, adentrando na análise legal do tema, inicialmente é oportuno fazer referência à Constituição Federal de 1988, que foi muito clara ao dispor, no seu art. 5º, inciso X, "in verbis":

" X - são invioláveis a intimidade, a vida privada, a honra e a imagem das pessoas, assegurado o direito a indenização pelo dano material ou moral decorrente de sua violação".

Sem, também deixarmos claro que o legislador não deixou de pronunciar esta garantia de direito ao consumidor, que no caso em tela tem claramente uma relação de consumo entre autor e ré, onde pedimos vênia para transcrever:

Código de Defesa do Consumidor


    ``V a efetiva prevenção e reparação de danos patrimoniais e morais, individuais, coletivos e difusos";

Além de incansáveis decisões assegurando o direito líquido e certo de quem se encontrar lesado por fato

<< Pesquisar Jurisprudência >>

E, por estarem tais argumentos, cabe lembrar que estão presentes os pressupostos da responsabilidade civil deste resultado danoso.

Pois bem, superada toda essa discussão, nesse momento é imprescindível a discussão a respeito de outro assunto de extrema relevância nesta demanda: o "quantum" a ser fixado.

Logo de início, é importante considerar que a reparação, na qual se convertem em pecúnia os danos morais, devem ter caráter dúplice, ou seja, o que penaliza o ofensor, sancionando-o para que não volte a praticar o ato ilícito, bem como o compensatório, para que o ofendido, recebendo determinada soma pecuniária, possa amenizar os efeitos decorrentes do ato que foi vítima.

Ante esse raciocínio, deve-se sopesar, em cada caso concreto, todas as circunstâncias que possam influenciar na fixação do "quantum" indenizatório, levando em consideração que o dano moral abrange, além das perdas valorativas internas, as exteriorizadas no relacionamento diário pessoal, familiar, profissional e social do ofendido.

Deve-se lembrar ainda, por outro ângulo, que a indenização por danos morais deve ser fixada num montante que sirva de aviso à ré e à sociedade, como um todo, de que o nosso direito não tolera aquela conduta danosa impunemente, devendo a condenação atingir efetivamente, de modo muito significativo, o patrimônio da causadora do dano, para que assim o Estado possa demonstrar que o Direito existe para ser cumprido.

\section{DO PEDIDO}

Posto isso, requer a Vossa Excelência:

A citação da ré, no endereço inicialmente referido, para comparecer na audiência de instrução e julgamento a ser designada, e, querendo, apresentar resposta, sob pena de revelia e confissão quanto à matéria de fato;

Se digne Vossa Excelência considerar procedente o seu pedido, para o fim de condenar a ré ao pagamento de indenização no valor de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor), pelos danos materiais, mais o valor a ser arbitrado por Vossa Excelência em salários mínimos referentes ao dano moral, bem como das custas processuais e honorários advocatícios, na base de xx\% sobre o valor da condenação, tudo com a devida atualização.

Os benefícios da justiça gratuita, previsto na Lei 1.060/50, por ser o autor pessoa pobre na acepção jurídica do termo, não podendo arcar com as despesas processuais sem que cause prejuízos para sua sobrevivência.

\section{DAS PROVAS}

Protesta por todos os meios de prova em direito admitidos, depoimentos de testemunhas, bem como novas provas, documentais e outras, que eventualmente venham a surgir.

\section{DO VALOR DA CAUSA}

Dá-se à causa o valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor).

Termos em que

Pede Deferimento.

(Local, data, ano).

\vfill

\begin{center}
\rule{6cm}{.4pt}\\
    Advogado: Fulano\\
    OAB-PR 123 \\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article} %showframe
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=4.3cm, bottom=3.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %%%caracteres latinos

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\section*{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS
EXCELENTÍSSIMO SENHOR DOUTOR JUIZ DE DIREITO DA 000ª VARA CÍVEL DA COMARCA DE XXXXXX}


(Nome), (nacionalidade), (estado civil), (profissão), portador da carteira de identidade RG n° xxxxxxx e inscrito no CPF/MF sob n° xxxxxxx, residente e domiciliado na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), por seu advogado que esta subscreve, constituído na forma do incluso instrumento de mandato, vem, a presença de Vossa Excelência, propor a presente.

\section*{AÇÃO DE INDENIZAÇÃO POR DANOS MORAIS E MATERIAIS}

contra (Razão social), pessoa jurídica de direito privado, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob n° xxxxxx, sediada na (Rua), (número), (bairro), (CEP), (Cidade), (Estado), consubstanciado nos motivos fáticos e de direito a seguir aduzidos:

\subsection*{DOS FATOS}

O autor foi até o Banco Tal para obter empréstimo no valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor), para comprar as ferramentas necessárias para uma pequena oficina de máquinas de costura.

Depois das exigências do Banco, onde o autor já havia superado todas, foi surpreendido com a negativação da concessão do numerário almejado.

Ao indagar, junto à gerência, o motivo de o Banco não liberar o empréstimo, mais uma vez foi surpreendido com a informação de que em seu nome havia restrição junto ao Serviço de Proteção ao Crédito.

Pediu ao funcionário do Banco que lhe desse tal informação por escrito, pois tinha certeza de que não devia nada a ninguém, senão seria desprovido de vergonha em querer um empréstimo, sabendo das normas do Banco, e em seguida passar por uma vergonha sem valores para o respeito, que até então havia conquistado junto àquela instituição.

O documento, que o autor recebeu do Banco, traz a informação de que seu nome consta no rol dos inadimplentes por atraso no pagamento de conta telefônica, datada de xx/xx/xx e com valor facial de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor).

Ocorre que o autor nunca ficou devendo nenhuma conta para a ré, e que ao buscar explicações junto à empresa ré foi informado que houve um erro de comunicação junto ao órgão de proteção ao crédito, porém que caberia a ele providenciar a retirada do seu nome do rol dos inadimplentes.

Indignado, o autor exigiu que retirassem seu nome daquela lista, obtendo a resposta de que fariam, mas isto levaria tempo.

Assim o autor teve seu nome negativado, sem dever nada a ninguém, por um período de trinta e cinco dias, e neste período teve prejuízos incalculáveis para a sua realidade econômica.

Toda esta narrativa de fatos objetiva dar a perfeita interação sobre o ocorrido, que pode ser sintetizado nos seguintes termos: ficou claro que a ré, de forma irresponsável, deixou que se incluísse o nome do autor no rol dos inadimplentes do serviço de proteção ao crédito, trazendo ao autor grande prejuízo, pois buscava empréstimo para iniciar um pequeno negócio de concerto de máquinas de costura, e ao questionar o ocorrido a autora não obteve nenhuma resposta plausível que solucionasse o caso imediatamente, sofrendo grande prejuízo.

Assim, nada mais justo, venha o autor requerer judicialmente uma reparação por tal fato.

\subsection*{DO DIREITO}

Em nosso direito é certa e pacífica a tese de que quando alguém viola um interesse de outrem, juridicamente protegido, fica obrigado a reparar o dano daí decorrente. Basta adentrar na esfera jurídica alheia, para que venha certa a responsabilidade civil.

E no caso particular, deve-se considerar que dano é "qualquer lesão injusta a componentes do complexo de valores protegidos pelo Direito".

No mesmo entendimento de dano material, temos a definição clara e objetiva de que a subtração de um objeto de outrem deverá devolver a coisa em espécie, e se o objeto não mais existir, deverá o esbulhador pagar o preço ordinário da coisa, ou repor o numerário a título de dano material, além do valor referente ao dano moral do autor, que ao buscar um empréstimo, junto ao banco, teve resposta negativa por motivos alheio a sua vontade.

Sendo assim, não há como confundir a reparabilidade do dano material e do dano moral. Na primeira busca-se a reposição do numerário que deu causa ao prejuízo sofrido, ao passo que na segunda, a reparação se faz por meio de uma compensação ou reparação que satisfaça o autor pelo mal sofrido.

Pois bem, adentrando na análise legal do tema, inicialmente é oportuno fazer referência à Constituição Federal de 1988, que foi muito clara ao dispor, no seu art. 5º, inciso X, "in verbis":

" X - são invioláveis a intimidade, a vida privada, a honra e a imagem das pessoas, assegurado o direito a indenização pelo dano material ou moral decorrente de sua violação".

Sem, também deixarmos claro que o legislador não deixou de pronunciar esta garantia de direito ao consumidor, que no caso em tela tem claramente uma relação de consumo entre autor e ré, onde pedimos vênia para transcrever:

Código de Defesa do Consumidor


\begin{enumerate}[label= \bfseries Artigo \arabic*º]
\setcounter{enumi}{5}

\item [...]

\begin{enumerate}[label = \Roman*]
    \setcounter{enumii}{5}
    \item a efetiva prevenção e reparação de danos patrimoniais e morais, individuais, coletivos e difusos";
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Além de incansáveis decisões assegurando o direito líquido e certo de quem se encontrar lesado por fato

<< Pesquisar Jurisprudência >>

E, por estarem tais argumentos, cabe lembrar que estão presentes os pressupostos da responsabilidade civil deste resultado danoso.

Pois bem, superada toda essa discussão, nesse momento é imprescindível a discussão a respeito de outro assunto de extrema relevância nesta demanda: o "quantum" a ser fixado.

Logo de início, é importante considerar que a reparação, na qual se convertem em pecúnia os danos morais, devem ter caráter dúplice, ou seja, o que penaliza o ofensor, sancionando-o para que não volte a praticar o ato ilícito, bem como o compensatório, para que o ofendido, recebendo determinada soma pecuniária, possa amenizar os efeitos decorrentes do ato que foi vítima.

Ante esse raciocínio, deve-se sopesar, em cada caso concreto, todas as circunstâncias que possam influenciar na fixação do "quantum" indenizatório, levando em consideração que o dano moral abrange, além das perdas valorativas internas, as exteriorizadas no relacionamento diário pessoal, familiar, profissional e social do ofendido.

Deve-se lembrar ainda, por outro ângulo, que a indenização por danos morais deve ser fixada num montante que sirva de aviso à ré e à sociedade, como um todo, de que o nosso direito não tolera aquela conduta danosa impunemente, devendo a condenação atingir efetivamente, de modo muito significativo, o patrimônio da causadora do dano, para que assim o Estado possa demonstrar que o Direito existe para ser cumprido.

\subsection*{DO PEDIDO}

Posto isso, requer a Vossa Excelência:

A citação da ré, no endereço inicialmente referido, para comparecer na audiência de instrução e julgamento a ser designada, e, querendo, apresentar resposta, sob pena de revelia e confissão quanto à matéria de fato;

Se digne Vossa Excelência considerar procedente o seu pedido, para o fim de condenar a ré ao pagamento de indenização no valor de R\$ xxxxxx (Valor), pelos danos materiais, mais o valor a ser arbitrado por Vossa Excelência em salários mínimos referentes ao dano moral, bem como das custas processuais e honorários advocatícios, na base de xx% sobre o valor da condenação, tudo com a devida atualização.

Os benefícios da justiça gratuita, previsto na Lei 1.060/50, por ser o autor pessoa pobre na acepção jurídica do termo, não podendo arcar com as despesas processuais sem que cause prejuízos para sua sobrevivência.

\subsection*{DAS PROVAS}

Protesta por todos os meios de prova em direito admitidos, depoimentos de testemunhas, bem como novas provas, documentais e outras, que eventualmente venham a surgir.

\subsection*{DO VALOR DA CAUSA}

Dá-se à causa o valor de R\$ xxxxx (Valor).

Termos em que

Pede Deferimento.

(Local, data, ano).

\vfill

\begin{table}[htb!]
    \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
    \cline{2-1}
    &Advogado: Fulano\\
    &OAB-PR 123 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good, but you don't need a table, which will float, just a tabular is enough, or maybe not even that.